# Properties of numbers picked from sets.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, pigeonhole-principle

So this is a two-part, pigeonhole principle exercise.

**The first part**:

Prove that if we choose ***n+2*** numbers from the following set:

```
{1,2,3,...,2n-1}
```

then the sum of two of those numbers will be equal to a third number we chose.

**The second part**:

Find one subset of **[2n-1]** which contains ***n+1*** elements in which there is no sum of two numbers equal to a third number of the subset.

Comment: @mees-de-vries The first set we will choose will be the n+2 and n+1 numbers we chose respectively.I can't understand what will be the second set.I guess I am confused with the third number.Does it contain pairs from which the first number is a pair of the two numbers and the second number is the sum?

Comment: Does it work for small values of $n$? Such as $n=3, 4$?

Comment: @KostasManiac Are you sure that your statement is correct?

Comment: @RobertZ You mean the exercise?It is translated from greek as it was originally written.

Comment: @KostasManiac I think that something is wrong with the text of your exercise. If $n=3$ then it is not possible to find a subset of $n+1=4$ elements in $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$  such that there is no sum of two numbers equal to a third number of the subset. Do you agree?

Comment: @robert-z Absolutely.Strange.Will ask for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

**The first part:** It suffices to prove that we can choose at most $n+1$ elements in set $B= \{ 1,2, \ldots , n \}$ so that no sum of two numbers from $n+1$ is equal to one of $n+1$ numbers.

Indeed, let $t$ is maximum element in $B$
Then at most one of $\{ i,t-i \}$ is element of $B$ where $i=1,2,...,\lfloor \frac{t}{2} \rfloor$.
And since $t$ is maximum element, we get that $$|B| \leq \lfloor \frac{t}{2} \rfloor +1 \leq \lfloor \frac{2n+1}{2} \rfloor +1 =n+1.$$

**The second part:** We can't always construct such set $B$ for all $n$. From the above proof, you can notice that we only deal with the condition where $a+b=2n+1$ where $2n+1 \in B$, but not for others $x \in B$. The first part only gives us a weak upper bound of $|B|$ of such set $B$.

Not related: This set $B$ is called sum-free set. Erdos proved that for any $n$ positive integers, we can choose at least $\frac 13 n$ numbers to create a sum-free subset.